# Can't solve this: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

Can't solve this:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.class

Orginal Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo' }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'urAndroid'
            keyPassword 'ab123'
            storePassword 'ab'
            storeFile file('../cer/android.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    lintOptions {
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.holandago.ur.ur"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 66
        versionName "2.9.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            ext.betaDistributionEmails = "abr@gmail.com"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = "Release Notes for this build."
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:0.3.3'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.+'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0-beta.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:1.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
}
```

Tried this Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://clojars.org/repo' }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'urAndroid'
            keyPassword 'ab123'
            storePassword 'ab'
            storeFile file('../cer/android.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    lintOptions {
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.holandago.ur.ur"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 66
        versionName "2.9.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            ext.betaDistributionEmails = "abr@gmail.com"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = "Release Notes for this build."
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
/*    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'*/
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:0.3.3'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.+'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0-beta.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:1.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // Optional -- Hamcrest library
    /*androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'*/
}
```

EDIT:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugAndroidTest]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. Incremental java
>   compilation is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers137Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta115Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics256Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore239Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife801Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMapboxMapboxsdkMapboxAndroidSdk410Beta1Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMapboxMapboxsdkMapboxAndroidServices110Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComMapzenAndroidLost110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComMixpanelAndroidMixpanelAndroid464Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview200Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug :app:generateDebugResValues
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources :app:mergeDebugResources
>   :app:processDebugResources :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prePackageMarkerForDebug :app:unzipJacocoAgent UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithJacocoForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateDebugSigning :app:packageDebug :app:zipalignDebug
>   :app:assembleDebug :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidexInstrumentation101Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore23AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource23AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIntents23AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoWeb23AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish06AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules06AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner06AlphaLibrary
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:incrementalDebugAndroidTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prePackageMarkerForDebugAndroidTest
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   >     org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.class

Comment: You don't have to compile the `hamcrest-core` library. You need only the `hamcrest-library`. The previous one will be added automatically. Please try to recompile the project again without the core library but first don't forget to clean the project. It should work.

Comment: @Blehi Did not work. This error happens when I run my test class.

Comment: remove    `testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'` and `androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'`

Comment: Nothing yet.nothing works

Comment: @piotrek1543 nothing works